# Archiving allegro program in xcode

Tags: allegro, allegro5

I have been trying to get my game working as an archived application in xcode, but I cannot get it to run at all.  The game runs in the normal run and profile mode, just not after it is archived.  I am getting the following error message, which makes it seem like I don't have a main function at all.

```
Dyld Error Message:
Symbol not found: __al_mangled_main
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/liballegro_main.5.1.dylib
Expected in: flat namespace
in /usr/local/lib/liballegro_main.5.1.dylib
```

I have also tried to build the application with the frameworks to no avail.

Here are my build settings

- header search path: /usr/local/include
- library search path: /usr/local/lib
- user header search path: "$(PROJECT_DIR)/..", "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
- always search user paths: yes

I also have an example project at https://github.com/tmuntan1/allegro-example

Thank you for your help

**Edit 1**:

Here is the error message with the frameworks

```
Dyld Error Message:
Symbol not found: __al_mangled_main
Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/app.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/AllegroMain-5.1.framework/Versions/5.1.6/AllegroMain-5.1
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/USER/Desktop/app.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/AllegroMain-5.1.framework/Versions/5.1.6/AllegroMain-5.1
```

**Edit 2**:

I solved my issue but I am not as happy with the solution. If I go and "build for archive" and find the release in the derived data it works. It only doesn't work if I build the archive and get the application through the organizer.

Answer (score 1):

I'had this exact problem, I finally solved it by replacing the definition of main function:

```
 int main(void)
```

by:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
```